# How can I programmatically log in to google+?

Tags: authentication, cookies, google-plus

Google+ is cool, sadly it lacks an official API.

However, I was able to reverse engineer the protocol used to retrieve the feed that a logged in G+ user gets. The URL to use is this:

[https://plus.google.com/_/stream/getactivities/?&sp=[1,2,null,null,null,10,null,\"social.google.com\",[]](https://plus.google.com/_/stream/getactivities/?&sp=%5B1,2,null,null,null,10,null,%5C%22social.google.com%5C%22,%5B%5D%5D)]

This gives you a nice JSON response containing all feeds that you get in G+ web interface.

However, the problem is that this URL only works correctly if you have already authenticated with your google account and you are able to set cookies properly. Otherwise the feed is empty.

The question is: how do I get the authentication cookie from outside of the browser (e.g. from a desktop client)?

I have tried multiple things, for example [this](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html) (appending oauth_token to the request URL), but nothing works.

Any ideas?

Janusz